# hotchocolate schema stitching with another language server

Tags: c#, graphql, hotchocolate

I have a question for a custom scalar converter and schema stitching. I want to stitch a schema from a third party Server and from my own server.
But the other server uses Java and a "BigDecimal" Type.
And when I load the schema in "banana cake pop" or any other UI tool (postman, insomnia) I get the following error on the server:

> "1. Unable to resolve type reference `BigDecimal`. (HotChocolate.Types.ObjectType)".

I have written my own Scalar ([like so](https://compiledexperience.com/blog/posts/new-scalars), [or so](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v13/defining-a-schema/scalars/#custom-scalars)) BigDecimal type and it is visible in the schema but it isn't used for the BigDecimal Scalar from the thirdparty server.

Is there a way to allow or overwrite thirdparty Scalars so I can use them in .net?
Is it even possible to have custom types which comes from other graphql services? I couldn't find anything to it on the internet.

Thanks and Best Regards in advance